# Replace two rows in R dataframe by one row containing their mean

Tags: r, dataframe, row, subset, average

I want to know what's the best way to replace two rows in a dataframe in R with just one row containing the average values of those two rows?

For example, let's say I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
index<-c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4")
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c(5,2,9,4)
df<-data.frame(index, a,b)
```

And I want to replace rows id2 and id3 with just one row, id.average that contains the average values of id2 ((2+3)/2) and id3 ((2+9)2) so I want my dataframe to eventually look like this:

```
index<-c("id1", "id.average", "id4")
a<-c(1,2.5,4)
b<-c(5,5.5,4)
df<-data.frame(index, a,b)
```

I calculate the average of the rows like this:

```
df2<-df[c(-1)]
row.names(df2)<-df$index
average<-apply(df2[2:3,], 2, mean)
```

and then deleted rows 2 and 3 but then my row order got messed up (i.e. instead of having id4 be row #2, it's still row#4..) and don't know how to add the new row id.average so that it's row 2, in between row 1 (id1) and row 3 (id4)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick function for it:

```r
#' Replace 2 rows with 1 in a data.frame
#'
#' @param obj 'data.frame'
#' @param rownum 'integer', between 1 and the number of rows in 'obj'
#' @param func 'function', to apply to each column; this function must
#'   accept the 'na.rm=' argument; default 'mean'
#' @param fill if 'character' (including 'NA'), a static value to
#'   apply to non-numeric fields (including factors); if 'function', a
#'   function to run to programmatically determine the return value;
#'   this function is only called when there are two unique values to
#'   be reduced, so in the case of identical factors/strings, it is
#'   returned without using 'fill'
#' @param na.rm 'logical', passed directly to 'func'
#' @return 'data.frame' with either the same number of rows (if
#'   'rownum == nrow(obj)') or one fewer rows
rows2mean <- function(obj, rownum, func = mean, fill = NA, na.rm = TRUE) {
  if (length(rownum) > 1L) {
    warning("'rownum' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used")
    rownum <- rownum[1]
  }
  if (rownum < 1) {
    stop("'rownum' must be positive")
  } else if (rownum > nrow(obj)) {
    stop("'rownum' must not be greater than the number of rows")
  }
  # assumption: rownum is now in [1,nrow(obj)]
  before <- if (rownum > 1) obj[seq_len(rownum - 1L),,drop = FALSE] else NULL
  middle <- obj[unique(pmin(rownum + 0:1, nrow(obj))),,drop = FALSE]
  after <- if (rownum <= nrow(obj)) obj[-seq_len(rownum + 1L),,drop = FALSE] else NULL
  middle[] <- lapply(middle, function(el) {
    if (length(el) < 2) return(el)
    if (is.numeric(el)) return(func(el, na.rm = na.rm))
    if (el[[1]] == el[[2]]) return(el[[1]])
    if (is.function(fill)) return(fill(el)) else return(fill)
  })
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, list(before, as.data.frame(middle[1,,drop = FALSE]), after))
}
```

It intentionally allows the last row to be selected, effectively a no-op.

In action:

```r
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c(5,2,9,4)
df<-data.frame(index=as.character(seq_along(a)), a, b)

rows2mean(df, 2)
#   index   a   b
# 1   id1 1.0 5.0
# 2  <NA> 2.5 5.5
# 4   id4 4.0 4.0

rows2mean(df, 4)               # no-op
#   index a b
# 1   id1 1 5
# 2   id2 2 2
# 3   id3 3 9
# 4   id4 4 4
```

And use of various `fill=` options:

```r
rows2mean(df, 2, fill="unk")
#   index   a   b
# 1   id1 1.0 5.0
# 2   unk 2.5 5.5
# 4   id4 4.0 4.0

elem1 <- function(a) a[[1]]
rows2mean(df, 2, fill=elem1)
#   index   a   b
# 1   id1 1.0 5.0
# 2   id2 2.5 5.5
# 4   id4 4.0 4.0
rows2mean(df, 4, fill=elem1)   # still a no-op
#   index a b
# 1   id1 1 5
# 2   id2 2 2
# 3   id3 3 9
# 4   id4 4 4
```

There is a slight side-effect: if any non-numeric columns are `factor`s, then `fill` (or its return value) will silently be added to the `levels` of the factor. I believe this is a good thing, as the intention to use that as a value is unambiguous. (I do think, however, that the only two practical uses of `fill=` will be with the default `fill=NA`, or a function that provides a contextual-relevant value. Any other static return value seems entirely too coarse and wrong.)

Comment: Really well elaborated !

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```r
df$index = as.character(df$index)    
df_final = rbind(df[1,],c("id.average",apply(df[2:3,2:3],2,mean)),df[4,])
```

And the get the following output:

```r
> df_final
       index   a   b
1        id1   1   5
2 id.average 2.5 5.5
4        id4   4   4
```